# can we move the camera during camera calibration

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am calibrating the camera using the camera_calibration package.

I am wondering if the camera can be moved during camera calibration.

Is it equivalent to moving the checker board in various directions?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63514/can-we-move-the-camera-during--camera-calibration/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-05-26**:
It should make no difference, theoretically. Everything is relative - to one sitting in a car you are moving and he/she is still, to you - the car is moving and you are still. It make no difference on practice either though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's equivalent. *camera_calibration* only processes the image, so it will see no difference.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1